# Close the txt file and delete it

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have a problem with the last 2 lines of code in this function because the file `file.txt` is still open and is not deleted and `tmpFile.txt` does not change the name.
Copying from `file.txt` to `tmpFile.txt` works great.
I'm asking for help

```java
public static void transfer(Client client) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        File file = new File("file.txt");
        File tmpFile = new File("tmpFile.txt");

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tmpFile));

        try{
            String lineToRemove = client.id + ";" + client.pin + ";" + 
                    client.money + ";" + client.name + ";";
            String currentLine;

            while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
                if(trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove)) continue;
                writer.write(currentLine + "\n");
            }
        }
        finally{
            writer.close();
            reader.close();
        }

        file.delete();
        tmpFile.renameTo(file);

        /*File oldFile = new File("tmpFile.txt");
        File newFile = new File(oldFile.getParent(), "file.txt");
        Files.move(oldFile.toPath(), newFile.toPath());*/
    }
```

Comment: When you say problem, what is the problem you are having ? An exception ? Your code works fine though

Comment: `file.delete()` returns a boolean telling you whether the file was deleted (true) or not (false) — have you checked the return value? I prefer `Files.delete(java.nio.file.Path)` because it throws an IOException telling you why the delete failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I run your code without the `Client` stuff, It works as expected.

The reason you still see your `file.txt` open is because that is NOT your initial `file.txt`. It's the renamed `tmpFile.txt`  that now is called `file.txt`.

With the code below you are left with a file that was renamed from `tmpFile.txt` to `file.txt` and it containes "HALLO\n". The initial file `file.txt` is in fact removed, and doesn`t exist anymore. - thats expected behaviour.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File file = new File("src/file.txt");
        File tmpFile = new File("src/tmpFile.txt");

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tmpFile));

        try{
                writer.write("HALLO" + "\n");
        }
        finally {
            writer.close();
            reader.close();
        }

        file.delete();
        tmpFile.renameTo(file);

    /*File oldFile = new File("tmpFile.txt");
    File newFile = new File(oldFile.getParent(), "file.txt");
    Files.move(oldFile.toPath(), newFile.toPath());*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unable to reproduce. I ran your code and it replaced the file.

But, try upgrading the code to use the newer NIO.2 methods:

```
public static void transfer(Client client) throws IOException {
    Path file = Paths.get("file.txt");
    Path tmpFile = Paths.get("tmpFile.txt");

    try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(file);
         BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(tmpFile)) {

        String lineToRemove = client.id + ";" + client.pin + ";" + 
                client.money + ";" + client.name + ";";
        for (String currentLine; (currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
            if (! currentLine.trim().equals(lineToRemove))
                writer.write(currentLine + "\n");
        }
    }

    Files.move(tmpFile, file, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```